# Multiple sapper apps from an existing nodejs express server

Tags: svelte, sapper

Some background

We have a singe nodejs express server serving multiple angular apps (using angular workspace and angular universal)
Each angular app is served via a specific route using SSR (universal) and shared components and resources (workspace)

We are looking into the option of moving to svelte (sapper/svelte kit)

1. <strike>I haven't found any docs on how to create a workspace for multiple svelte apps in order to share components, css and more between separate apps</strike>

***Edit:*** Of course this can be done manually rather simply as suggested in the comments and since svelte is not a framerwork (like angular) maybe the intention is not to create a 'svelte' way of doing this.

2. Serve the relevant sapper app from an existing fully fledged nodejs express app.

Is it possible? If so, can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: The second part is similar to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65214871/a-sapper-compatible-setup-to-serve-multiple-apps-from-a-single-express-polka-ent which hasn't been answered yet. I hope at least one of us will get some clues.
As for the first part of your question, if your applications are hosted in a common folder/filesystem, you can normally import any component or library into any of your applications (I don't suppose you mean something more specific by "workspace").